# transform an array to square matrix(2D matrix) by function

Tags: javascript, matrix

I have got a little function in java script and I want to split an array A into a 2d array(square array).

```
function twoDimensional(array, row) {
    let newArray = [];
    let arraySize = Math.floor(array.length / row);
    let extraArraySize = array.length % row;
    while (array.length) {
      if (!!extraArraySize) {
        newArray.push(array.splice(0, arraySize + 1));
        extraArraySize--;
      } else {
        newArray.push(array.splice(0, arraySize));
      }
    }

    return newArray;
  }
```

I want to get an array from input and converts it to a **square array**.

Matrices should be padded on the right or at the bottom, but not
both simultaneously (for example the size of the biggest direction shouldn't
change).

If the input is already a square matrix, just return that matrix.

for example:

```
Input: [1,2]    => output : [[1,2],[0,0]]

Input: [[6,2],[4,9]] => output : [[6,2],[4,9]]

Input: [[3,2],[9,9],[4,8]] => output : [[3,2,0],[9,9,0],[4,8,0]]
```

could you help me How I can change my Function to get above outputs?

any solutions would be my appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I'd do it.

```js
//input output pairs
const ioPairs = [{
  input: [[1,2]],
  output: [[1,2],[0,0]]
}, {
  input: [[6,2],[4,9]],
  output: [[6,2],[4,9]]
}, {
  input: [[3,2],[9,9],[4,8]],
  output: [[3,2,0],[9,9,0],[4,8,0]]
}];

//solution
function squareMatrix(input) {
  const output = [];
  const size = Math.max(input.length, input[0].length);
  
  for (let row of input) {
    //pad right
    row = [...row];
    while (row.length < size) {
      row.push(0);
    }
    
    output.push(row);
  }
  
  //pad bottom
  while (output.length < size) {
    const blanks = (new Array(size)).fill(0);
    output.push(blanks);
  }
  
  return output;
}

//testing
for (let ioPair of ioPairs) {
  const actualOutput = squareMatrix(ioPair.input);
  const expectedOutput = ioPair.output;
  console.log('input:', ioPair.input);
  if (JSON.stringify(actualOutput) === JSON.stringify(expectedOutput)) {
    console.log('output:', actualOutput);
  } else {
    console.log('actualOutput:', actualOutput);
    console.log('expectedOutput:', expectedOutput);
  }
  console.log('---');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function twoDimensional(array) {
    let newArray = [];
    let matrixSize = array.length;
    array.forEach((element) => {
        if (element.length && element.length > matrixSize) {
            matrixSize = element.length;
        }
    });
    for (let i = 0; i < matrixSize; i++) {
        let row = array[i] || [];
        if (typeof array[i] === "number") {
            row = [array[i]];
        }
        let toFill = matrixSize - row.length;
        while (toFill > 0) {
            row.push(0);
            toFill--;
        }
        newArray.push(row);
    }
    return newArray;
}
console.log("Input:", [1, 2]);
console.log(twoDimensional([1, 2]));
console.log("Input:", [[6, 2],[4, 9]]);
console.log(twoDimensional([[6, 2],[4, 9]]));
console.log("Input:", [[3, 2],[9, 9],[4, 8]]);
console.log(twoDimensional([[3, 2],[9, 9],[4, 8]]));
```

Comment: your code works. just take a look into console.log("Input:", [1, 2]);
console.log(twoDimensional([1, 2]));
output is wrong!!

Comment: @zigzag It do works, but your first input is [1, 2] ,  that should be converted to [ [1,0],[2,0] ]. Look that it's different if your input is: [ [1,2] ]. Check the other answer, the input is [ [1,2] ] as I say.

Comment: .as I said , Input: [1,2]    => output should be: [[1,2],[0,0]] not  [ [1,0],[2,0] ] .other cases works well

Answer (score 0):

What you mean is probably transform a rectangular matrix to a square matrix by the output you've provided.

```js
let test1 = [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4],
    [5, 6],
];

let test2 = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
];

let test3 = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
];

console.log(toSquareMatrix(test1));
console.log(toSquareMatrix(test2));
console.log(toSquareMatrix(test3));

function toSquareMatrix(args) {
    let colCount = args[0].length;
    let rowCount = args.length;
    let result = [];

    if (colCount === rowCount) {
        return "You already have a square matrix";
    } else if (rowCount > colCount) {
        result = args.map((row) => {
            while (row.length /**col */ < rowCount) {
                row.push(0);
            }
            return row;
        });
    } else if (colCount > rowCount) {
        while (args.length < colCount) args.push(Array(colCount).fill(0));
        result = args;
    }
    return result;
}
```